# "requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system" even after successful apt-get install

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit, composer-php

I'm trying to

> $composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^6.5

and get the following error:

```
 Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

So I ran the following multiple times

> $sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

and get

```
php-mbstring is already the newest version (1:7.2+60ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

> $ php --ini

Gives:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

<s>I've also uncommitted the 
`extension=php_mbstring.dll`
 line in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`</s>  *(irrelevant/wrong action)*

And I still get the "`mbstring is missing from your system`" error.

*I'm on Ubuntu 18.04*

**EDIT:**
<s>the composer command also gives:</s>

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Yes, un-commenting `extension=php_mbstring.dll` in php.ini on ubuntu was wrong/irrelevant (see comment)

Comment: You are using Ubuntu, but `php_mbstring.dll` is a Windows library.  Linux is `php_mbstring.so`.

Comment: it is possible that your host has several php version installed and that you are just installing ext mb string for the default version, not the one actually in use. Try apt-get install phpx.x-mbstring with x.x being the acutal version used by the web server. Then of course, restart the web server and / or php fpm in case you use it

Comment: I've installed the latest php-mbstring and php7.2-mbstring

Comment: @KevinRenaers PHPUnit is a CLI-based tool, only the CLI SAPI of PHP is relevant. Therefore there is no need to restart a webserver.